# ARM template deployment does not copy over files or setting in devops release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-data-factory

Im trying to set up and test CI/CD integration in Azure datafactory. As for now i have connected the datafactory to git, set up a new enviroment with all the same resources (datafactory, blobstorage, sql database). I have set up my arm template to copy over the "test" datafactory to dev/publish datafactory in devops pipeline release. I did this by connecting directly to the git repository (the publish branch). When i run the release pipeline, everything seems to be fine, and the template works (it connects to the new resources in the new enviroment etc.) The pipeline is set up with the same setting. However, when i try to run the pipeline it does not work (the publish pipeline).

I have narrowed it down to the that it does not seem that the arm template copies over my csv files or makes new entries to database, however on several of the guides/youtube videos i have seen they seem to get this right.

Does anyone know what the issue might be, and if it is possible to get arm template deployment to copy over the files? If not, if there are any other functions in pipeline release that can do this insted.

I have tried to manually add the containers in blob storage, and query the databse table, and then the rest of the pipeline seems to work fine.

Comment: The ARM template is just for the Data Factory itself.  I am a little confused in your question with the terms 'release pipeline' which works and 'publish pipeline' which doesn't.  Where are these csv files residing that need to be copied over, are they in the repo or somewhere else?  I have used the Azure CLI task in the DevOps Release pipeline to copy files to blob storage, that may be what you need.

Comment: The goal is essentialy to have a "production" and "development" type system, where you can push the changes in the development pipeline to the production one. Just as a test, i have sql database and blob storage in this development factory. When i i set up the release pipeline, the whole datafactory and linked service seem to be set up correctly in the production datafactory after release. However, the csv files that reside in the blob storage in the same resource group, dont seem to get "copied" over to the blob storage in the production enviroment.

Comment: You will need another step in your DevOps release pipeline to copy the blobs over.  The blobs are not part of the Data Factory so they are not in the ARM template.  You can use the Azure CLI task to accomplish the copying of blobs over to production.